# Alternatives to Radio Transceivers

Tags: arduino-uno

So i am creating a haunt project that needs a way of detecting when an Arduino passes it and makes that Arduino do something. the problem I'm having is that none of the transmitter and receiver that has a small enough range that won't interfere with other patrons walking through on the other side of the wall. does anyone have any ideas what i can use?

Comment: Not a question about Arduino

Comment: RFID tags would be fitting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a discussion of a similar question at the [Arduino forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/arduino-rfid-tag-detection/139570) where they leaned towards passive UHF RFID tags.

If your budget stretches to it, there would be a range of active RFID tags that might suit.

There’s a good [intro to RFID](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/rfid-basics/all) at Sparkfun, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification) has a good starting reference point.